Nat Gateway Profile for AKS using terraform
Hi I want to use userAssignedNatGateway for my private aks cluster.
Could anyone help me with network profile block for aks how can I pass the nat gateway that I've created using terraform only
Even I tried with outbound count as 2 still facing issue.
network_profile{
# other network configuration 
outbound_type="userAssignedNatGateway"
nat_gateway_profile{
 mamaged_outbound_ip_count = 2
 }
}


please share the code you tried so far @jonty


Nat Gateway Profile for AKS using terraform

It's possible to achieve this requirement declaring the network profile inside the AKS cluster configuration.
This can be achieved by  creating a user-assigned NAT Gateway for your private AKS cluster & create a NAT Gateway and assign it to your AKS cluster’s subnet then add the network_profile block to pass the NAT Gateway configuration.
Configuration:
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "nat_gateway_public_ip" {
  name                = "nat-gateway-public-ip"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"
}


resource "azurerm_nat_gateway" "nat_gateway" {
  name                = "vinay-nat-gateway"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku_name            = "Standard"
}


resource "azurerm_nat_gateway_public_ip_association" "nat_gateway_ip" {
  nat_gateway_id      = azurerm_nat_gateway.nat_gateway.id
  public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.nat_gateway_public_ip.id
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example_vnet" {
  name                = "vinay-vnet"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}


resource "azurerm_subnet" "aks_subnet" {
  name                 = "aks-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example_vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}


resource "azurerm_subnet_nat_gateway_association" "aks_subnet_nat_gateway_association" {
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.aks_subnet.id
  nat_gateway_id = azurerm_nat_gateway.nat_gateway.id
}


resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks_cluster" {
  name                = "vinay-aks"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  dns_prefix          = "exampleaks"

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 1
    vm_size    = "Standard_DS2_v2"
    vnet_subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.aks_subnet.id  
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  
  network_profile {
    network_plugin    = "azure"
    load_balancer_sku = "standard"
    outbound_type     = "userAssignedNATGateway"  

    load_balancer_profile {
      outbound_ip_address_ids = [azurerm_public_ip.nat_gateway_public_ip.id]
    }

    
    service_cidr      = "10.1.0.0/16"  
    dns_service_ip    = "10.1.0.10"    
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_subnet_nat_gateway_association.aks_subnet_nat_gateway_association
  ]
}

Deployment:



refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/nat-gateway
azure - How to create a private AKS cluster in an existing VNET using Terraform - Stack Overflow

is there any way to pass the nat IP in the config file? or will it automatically assign the IP associated with it the subnets?

I updated the solution please check one @Jonty

understood thanks a lot @vinay
